# How to fetch data from AWS S3 bucket using Django Rest API

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to fetch my media files from a django rest api using a jquery async function, this function worked fine in development but now I've deployed the app to Heroku and my media files are being served by an AWS S3 bucket, so this fetch function doesn't work anymore.

music.js

```
   async function getUserTracks() {
      await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/music_all/?format=json")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          for (item of data)
            trackNames.push(item['title']),
              trackUrl.push(item['track']),
              albums.push(item['artist_name'])
          // console.log(trackNames, trackUrl, albums)
        });
    }
```

As you can see the fetch url is a localhost address, my question is how can I fetch these files, now that they are in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a library like [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - it will walk you through how reference you AWS S3 bucket easily and then you can pull your file from AWS with a simple method.

Good luck, follow up with any other questions.

Comment: thanks, I already have django-storages installed, it works well with the django rest api running locally, and extracts from AWS , but now that the apps on Heroku , the fetch function doesn't work. I've even tried changing the fetch url to the new heroku api root url, but still no luck

Comment: Do you have a specific error code you are trying to debug? I would assume it is a security/permissions issue of some sort: It could be
1. Your Heroku permissions do not allow you to download files from your AWS bucket - you would need to whitelist them.
2. Your AWS permissions do not allow requests from your Heroku server - you would need to whitelist the Heroku IP address
3. Your Webserver doens't allow either Heroku or AWS based on your Django-Settings.